# WebBrowserDocumentCompleted

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

how to make that ongoing actions WebBrowserDocumentCompleted worked in a separate thread. And so it does not affect the main form (not hang the entire application)

**Form1**

```
private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            wb.Navigate("http://www.moswar.ru");
        }
```

**Form2**

```
    public void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                wb = sender as WebBrowser;
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((object unused) =>

                    {

                        if (wb.Document.GetElementById("login-email") != null)
                        {
                            wb.Document.GetElementById("login-email").InnerText = "myemail@blah.pe";
                            wb.Document.GetElementById("login-password").InnerText = "MyPassword";
                           GetElementsByClassName(new string[] { "button luxury" })[0].InvokeMember("click");
                        }


                if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri == "http://www.moswar.ru/player/" || e.Url.AbsoluteUri == "http://www.moswar.ru/player/#login")
                {
                    wb.Navigate("http://www.moswar.ru/metro/");
                }
                    }));
            //and so on .....
            }
```

Comment: Be careful when you write your email and some passwords in forums like this. I was able to log in the site cause you left your info. I edited and removed it :)

Comment: This account is not very dear to me =)) Important to me how to solve my problem =))

Answer (score 0):

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
  {
    MessageBox.Show("hi");
  }
}
```

Comment: **It does not help**
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((object unused) =>
                
     {
       //my methods
    
    }));
**All application hangs when DocumentCompleted begins to follow links**

Comment: @GeKson of course, if you use WAITcallback it will WAIT until the action is finished. Edit your question and show your code. Also describe what "follow links" means. Leave here a comment if you are done